# Laravel displays "`Attempt to read property 'id' on null`" instead of SQL Error messages with PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-10

I'm encountering an issue with Laravel when using PostgreSQL.
When executing a query with a non-existent column, such as `Letter::where('aaa', 'dd')->get();` in a scenario where the `aaa` column does not exist in the `letter` table, I expect to receive an error message indicating that the column doesn't exist.

However, Laravel consistently returns the error message `Attempt to read property "id" on null` for any SQL errors, not just for missing columns.

How can I configure Laravel, or debug this issue to display specific SQL error messages, instead of the generic message about attempting to read a property on `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should mean that Laravel tries to access a property on a model instance that has not been instantiated due to an underlying SQL error.

Make sure your Laravel application is in [debug mode](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#configuration) to get more detailed error messages. That can be done by setting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file. However, be cautious with this setting in production environments.

And check that [logging](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/logging) is enabled in Laravel to capture all errors, including SQL errors. Laravel uses the [Monolog library](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), which allows for detailed error logging.

For instance, to catch database query exceptions and log them:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Log;

try {
    $letters = Letter::where('aaa', 'dd')->get();
} catch (QueryException $e) {
    Log::error($e->getMessage());
    // Optionally, return a more user-friendly message or take other appropriate actions
    return response()->json(['error' => 'A database error occurred.'], 500);
}
```

By catching `QueryException`, you can log the detailed error message or even return it in the response for debugging purposes. Note that exposing detailed error messages in a production environment can be a security risk.

You can also customize the [exception handling](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#the-exception-handler) in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file to catch and handle database-related exceptions more transparently.
Modify the [`render` or `report` methods](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#renderable-exceptions). That allows you to intercept specific exceptions, such as `QueryException`, and handle them accordingly.

Import the necessary exception classes at the top of your `Handler.php` file:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

The `report` method is used for logging exceptions. You can customize it to add specific logs for database exceptions if needed. That step is optional and based on your preference for logging:

```php
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        // Log the error or send it to an external service like Sentry or Bugsnag
        Log::error($exception->getMessage());
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

The `render` method is responsible for converting an exception into an HTTP response that is sent back to the client.

```php
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // Check if the exception is an instance of QueryException
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        // Determine if the app is in debug mode
        if (config('app.debug')) {
            // Return a more detailed error response in debug mode
            $errorResponse = [
                'error' => 'Database query error',
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'sql' => $exception->getSql(),
                'bindings' => $exception->getBindings(),
            ];
            return response()->json($errorResponse, Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } else {
            // Return a generic error response in production mode
            return response()->json(['error' => 'A database error occurred. Please try again later.'], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    // Process other exceptions as usual
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

When a `QueryException` is caught, you can decide how to respond based on whether your application is in debug mode. In debug mode, you could return detailed error information, including the SQL statement and bindings.
In production mode, you would typically return a generic error message to avoid exposing sensitive information.

---

The [OP Hosserin Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19214190/hosserin-ibrahim) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011274/laravel-displays-attempt-to-read-property-id-on-null-instead-of-sql-error/78025552?noredirect=1#comment137554410_78025552):

> My problem is solved. The problem is a line in my custom handler.
> I have programed the system to report any exception in telegram, if happen any error in handler no way to report this.
> Just solve this line and Laravel return query exceptions in Postgres.

Comment: thank you for answering, my problem is solved. the problem is a line in my custom handler. i'm programed the system to report any exception in telegram, if happen any error in handler no way to report this. just solve this line and Laravel return query exceptions in postgre thank you so much and in arabic: الله يرحم امك و ابوك

Comment: @HosserinIbrahim Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer to reflect your conclusion. Thank you for your kind words and prayers. In Arabic: "شكراً لك على كلماتك الطيبة ودعائك.".